# Adding ActionListeners to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

This questions has been asked a few times but mine is a little different. I created a small application and in the view I added a few JPanels to a JFrame. I then try to add actionListeners in the controller which is where the problem happened.

The code below gives me the following error:

```
The method addActionListener(new ActionListener(){})
is undefined for the type JPanel
```

The view class

```
public class MainMenuGUI {

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

JPanel findUserPanel;
JPanel deleteUserPanel;
JPanel addUserPanel;

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel tabbedPanel = new JPanel();

//Controller class for tabbedPanel
ControllerTabbedPane listen = new ControllerTabbedPane(this);
//Controller class for findUserPanel
FindUserPanelController findUserController = new FindUserPanelController(findUserPanel);

public MainMenuGUI() {

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    findUserPanel = createFindUserPanel();
    deleteUserPanel = createDeleteUserPanel();
    addUserPanel = createAddUserPanel();

    tabbedPane.addTab("Find User", findUserPanel);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Delete User", deleteUserPanel);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Add User", addUserPanel);

    tabbedPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.add(tabbedPanel);

    frame.pack();
    // opens frame in the center of the screen
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

JPanel createFindUserPanel() {
    findUserPanel = new JPanel();
    findUserPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    findUserPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 7));

    JLabel firstlbl = new JLabel("First Name");
    JLabel lastlbl = new JLabel("Last Name");
    JLabel addresslbl = new JLabel("Address");
    JLabel agelbl = new JLabel("Age");

    JTextField firstNametxt = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField lastNametxt = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField addresstxt = new JTextField(30);
    JTextField age = new JTextField(3);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Submit");
    JScrollPane window = new JScrollPane();
    window.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

    findUserPanel.add(firstlbl);
    findUserPanel.add(firstNametxt);
    findUserPanel.add(lastlbl);
    findUserPanel.add(lastNametxt);
    findUserPanel.add(addresslbl);
    findUserPanel.add(addresstxt);
    findUserPanel.add(agelbl);
    findUserPanel.add(age);
    findUserPanel.add(window, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    findUserPanel.add(btn);

    return findUserPanel;
}
```

Controller Class

```
 public class ControllerTabbedPane {

    MainMenuGUI mainMenuGUI;

    int currentTabbedIndex = 0;

    ControllerTabbedPane(MainMenuGUI mainMenuGUI){
        this.mainMenuGUI = mainMenuGUI;
        addTabbedPaneListeners();

    }

    private void addTabbedPaneListeners() {

        mainMenuGUI.tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {

                currentTabbedIndex = mainMenuGUI.tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println("Current tab is:" + currentTabbedIndex);

            }
        });
    }

    /*ERROR saying The method addActionListener(new ActionListener(){})
    is undefined for the type JPanel*/
    private void findPanelListeners() {

        mainMenuGUI.findUserPanel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });

    }
```

Comment: You can't register ActionListeners on JPanels. Perhaps you consider using a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) instead?

Comment: @PakkuDon but then how would I be able to tell if the button was pressed in the JPanel? I will also need to get the JTextFields values to set the model classes values.

Comment: *"I then try to add actionListeners in the controller which is where the problem happened."*  What problem?  And more importantly, what is your question?

Comment: @jocdrew21: If you have a button inside your JPanel then maybe you should be registering your ActionListener on the button instead?

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson In the codes comments I added questions to make it more comprehensible, for example /*ERROR saying The method addActionListener(new ActionListener(){})
is undefined for the type JPanel*/

Comment: @PakkuDon I did like this: mainMenuGUI.findUserPanel.btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() and it didn't work. I need for the controller to know which Jpanel I am trying to set the actionListener to?

Comment: *"In the codes comments I added questions to make it more comprehensible"*  Try adding a '?' to the end of them to make them more **findable.**  Also, for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to achieve your request:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JButton bt1 = new JButton();
JButton bt2 = new JButton();
panel1.add(bt1);
panel2.add(bt2);

bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Bt1 on panel1 pressed");
    }
});

bt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Bt2 on panel2 pressed");
    }
});
```

You can modify variables or other objects into the listeners to store which panel was "pressed".

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to add `addActionListner()` to `JPanel`

Instead

You can use,

```
 JPanel p1=new JPanel();
 p1.addMouseListener(this);
```

And override

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
{
  int x=me.getX();
  int y=me.getY();
  System.out.println(x+","+y);
    //By using x AND y you can identify the panel 

}
```

NB: `extends MouseAdapter`